# Wordpress Plugin - Firing twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for Wordpress that double-checks with users they are sure they want to publish posts:

```
<?php

$prompt = "are you sure you're ready to publish";

function confirm_publish(){
    global $prompt;
    print '

<script>

var publish = document.getElementById("publish");
if (publish !== null) publish.onclick = function(){
    return confirm("'.$prompt.'")
};

</script>';
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'confirm_publish');

?>
```

When the plugin is installed and we click publish, it is firing twice. It is currently hooked to `'admin_footer'` which should only fire once - yet it loops twice.

Why? and How can this be fixed to only pop up once?

Thanks
Joe